# adding active state in css to navigation bar

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/DaJWC/
i can't figure out how to make one of the links reverse so that it is blue to start with. also how would i make a line that is under the current page you are viewing as will.

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 525px;
}
ul#list-nav li {
  display: inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: ;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background: ;
  color: #09F
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="border_left">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="border_left">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="border_left">Get a Quote</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="border_left">Contact</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward. What have you tried that hasn't worked out for you? Also, your selectors are very specific. Might be overkill for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: adding a class to the item i want to be selected and putting it to blue but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the ":hover" from where you set the color. I would create a new selector like: ul#list-nav li a {...} and then you can pick colors for not-hover and hover. [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/DaJWC/4/).

Comment: could you js fiddle it please

Comment: check it! I set the color in ul#list-nav li a to #09F. There is a link in my original post.

Comment: so you just want "Home" to be blue and the rest black. Do you want any of them to change color when you mouse over them?

Comment: sorry for the vague question, yes i would like the home to be blue to black and the rest black to blue :)

Comment: okay [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/DaJWC/6/). I changed the color using the active class you created. Because of the circumstances I had to add !important to the rule because it must override the coloring of the other links.